# iphone/ipad adding adding and removing a subview doesnt work

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

Im have a slight amount of trouble adding a new view to my scene, I have the code like this:

```
- (void) showMyDayView {
NSLog(@"My Day View was touched");

MyDayViewController *temp = [[MyDayViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MyDayView" bundle:nil];
self.myDayViewController = temp;

NSLog(@"superview: %@", [[self mainNavView] superview]);
[[self mainNavView] removeFromSuperview];
NSLog(@"after removal main: %@", [self mainNavView]);
NSLog(@"after removal view: %@", [self view]);
NSLog(@"after removal superview: %@", [[self view] superview]);

[[[self view] superview] addSubview: [self.myDayViewController view]];

[temp release];
}
```

And when I run this code, the console says "after removal superview: (null)"

so when I add the subView to the superview, nothing happens because the superview is null.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reuse a view that you are going to removeFromSuperview, you must retain it first. removeFromSuperview releases any view it is invoked on.

So...

```
[[self mainNavView] retain]
[[self mainNavView] removeFromSuperview];
```

And [self mainNavView] remains safe to use.

Comment: so is the reason why the superview is made null because the mainNavView is released?

Comment: but still after adding the retain, its still nulled out

Comment: There must be something else releasing it then, adding a retain takes care of the removeFromSuperview. I'm still a bit confused about what you're doing, the identity and function of all your views isn't given.

Comment: im trying to insert a new view into my scene, my new view will be a uisplitview, hopefully, but im also not having much luck.

Comment: Have you mapped out exactly what relation these views have to each other? I'm not seeing what relation or relevance myDayViewController is apart from being some valid view to add as subview. Is [self view] the same object as [self mainNavView]? If so is it being changed by something else?

Comment: yeah sorry about that, im very new to all this still, I had a lot of spaghetti code lying around, Ive now cleaned it up, and your code is working fine :)